# ThinkPad T420 is not booting

Tags: linux, windows-7, bios, thinkpad

I bought a used T420 without a drive, I installed a Kingston SSD, but I still get this when trying to boot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FMLF.jpg Thanks for the help

Comment: Relevant information should be in the question text, not in linked images.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

New hard drives are empty. You need to install an operating system to them using a cd or usb drive.

Answer (score 0):

First I would try to manipulate the boot order moving your Kingston drive to the top. If that does not work I would remove the SSD make sure the connection is clean and reattach with care. If you still cannot boot resubmit your question with any new information.